# Topologically embed Klein bottle into $\mathbb{R}^4$ projecting to usual "beer-bottle" surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: gn.general-topology, embeddings

(Originally asked in 2018 at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946505/topological-embedding-of-klein-bottle-into-mathbbr4-that-projects-to-usual?noredirect=1#comment9514257_2946505;cross-posted here.)

What is an *explicit* topological embedding of the Klein bottle into $\mathbb{R}^4$ whose projection, of some sort, down to $\mathbb{R}^3$ gives the usual "beer-bottle" immersed surface (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8a/Surface_of_Klein_bottle_with_traced_line.svg), and then how does that embedding and the projection yield an explicit "topological immersion" of the Klein bottle into $\mathbb{R}^3$?

By a "topological immersion" I mean at least a continuous local homeomorphism.

What I’m looking for, more precisely, is a map $f: [a, b] \times [c, d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ with the following properties:

- $[a, b] = [c, d] = [0, 1]$, or perhaps more conveniently, $[a, b] = [c, d] = [0, 2 \pi]$;
- $f$ is constant on equivalence classes under the usual equivalence relation on the rectangle that identifies horizontal edges going in the same direction but identifies vertical edges in opposite directions;
- by passing to the quotient, $f$ induces an embedding $f^{\ast}$ of the Klein bottle $K$ into $\mathbb{R}^4$;
- the composite $g =  p \circ f^{\ast}$ is an immersion of $K$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose image is that “beer-bottle” surface $S$, where the "projection" $p$ has a form such as $p(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (x_1, x_2, x_3 \cos \alpha + x_4 \sin \alpha)$; and
- the composite $q \circ g$ is therefore a parameterization of that surface $S$, where $q : [a, b] \times [c, d] \to K$ is the quotient map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following functions (written in Maple code):

```
   klein_embedding := (t,u) -> 
   [(0.1*sin(3*Pi*t)+0.1*sin(Pi*t)+0.4*cos(Pi*t))*sin(2*Pi*u)-0.5*sin(4*Pi*t)+sin(2*Pi*t), 
 0.2*sin(2*Pi*u)*sin(3*Pi*t)+2.*cos(2*Pi*t)+0.5, 
 0.25*cos(2*Pi*u)*sin(2*Pi*t)+0.4*cos(2*Pi*u)];

   klein_seam_a := (t) -> [0.8621-0.0015*cos(4*Pi*t)+0.0171*sin(2*Pi*t)-0.0002*sin(6*Pi*t),t];

   klein_seam_b := (t) -> [0.1179+0.0031*cos(4*Pi*t)-0.0385*sin(2*Pi*t)+0.0005*sin(6*Pi*t), 
               0.75+0.0597*cos(2*Pi*t)-0.0004*cos(6*Pi*t)+0.0049*sin(4*Pi*t)];

   klein_seam := (t) -> [-0.2811+0.0051*cos(4*Pi*t)-0.1401*sin(2*Pi*t)+0.0005*sin(6*Pi*t), 
             1.7871-0.0061*cos(4*Pi*t)+0.3532*sin(2*Pi*t)-0.0005*sin(6*Pi*t), 
             0.2090*cos(2*Pi*t)-0.0010*cos(6*Pi*t)+0.0086*sin(4*Pi*t)];
```

The map `klein_embedding(t,u)` satisfies `klein_embedding(t,u)=klein_embedding(1+t,1-u)=klein_embedding(t,1+u)`, so it induces a map from the Klein bottle (defined as a quotient of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the usual way) to $\mathbb{R}^3$.  This is almost an embedding, with image as follows:
[image]

The other three functions relate to the curve $C$ of self-intersection in the image of `klein_embedding(t,u)`. All claims about these functions are only approximately true (but in principle there exist functions for which the claims hold exactly).

The map `klein_seam(t)` goes from $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ with image $C$.  Thus, there are two different maps $[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$ whose composite with `klein_embedding` is `klein_seam`, and these two functions are `klein_seam_a(t)` and `klein_seam_b(t)`.  Their effect is as follows:

[image]

`klein_seam_a(t)` gives the slightly curved red line on the right, and `klein_seam_b(t)` gives the small blue closed curve on the left.

Adding almost any function as a fourth coordinate in `klein_embedding(t,u)` will give an embedding in $\mathbb{R}^4$.  For example, `cos(Pi*t)` will work.

The above code is taken from https://github.com/NeilStrickland/maple_lib/blob/master/lib/geometry/geometry.mpl

The same repository also contains Maple code for many other things.

UPDATE: There are also more canonical embeddings
$$ K \xrightarrow{f} S^1\times S^2 \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb{R}^4 $$
given by
\begin{align*}
 f(t,u) &= (\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t),\cos(2\pi u),\cos(\pi t)\sin(2\pi u),\sin(\pi t)\sin(2\pi u)) \\
 g(a,b,x,y,z) &= ((2+x)a,(2+x)b,y,z)
\end{align*}
(The latter is closely analogous to the usual torus embedding $S^1\times S^1\to\mathbb{R}^3$.)

We can compose $gf$ with a linear projection $p\colon\mathbb{R}^4\to\mathbb{R}^3$ to get a map $pgf\colon K\to\mathbb{R}^3$, but experiment suggests that this is never an immersion, there are always singular points where the rank of the derivative drops to $1$.  I think it should not be too hard to give a formal proof of that, although I have not tried.  Anyway, this explains why we need some terms like $\sin(3\pi t)$ and $\sin(4\pi t)$ in `klein_embedding(t,u)`.

Comment: What is the meaning of the "magic" coefficients 0.8621, 0.0015, etc., that appear in the definition of the `klein_seam_`* functions? And why the particular coefficients 0.1, 0.4, 0.25, etc. in the definition of `klein_embedding`?

Comment: The coefficients in `klein_embedding` were adjusted experimentally to make the picture look nice.  If you change them by an amount that is not too large, you will still get an immersed Klein bottle.  For the other functions, I found a bunch of points on $C$ by numerical methods.  Then I used further numerical methods to find coefficients to make the `klein_seam` functions pass approximately through those points.

Comment: I'm really after a mathematically satisfying embedding, where the needed coefficients arise more or less naturally -- not merely something that looks good when rendered graphically.

Comment: @murray this seems a rather ungracious way to respond to someone who put in a great deal of effort to answer your question. What is it that you wanted to use this embedding for that this answer does not address?

Comment: @NeilStrickland: Your edits are particularly helpful. I've accepted your answer, since it does what I asked to be done. Now I'll play with it to see if I can find "nicer" coefficients that don't seem to be experimentally adjusted. Thank you!

Comment: @JimConant: This is for a (rigourous) exposition for those just learning topology (and not just for the purpose of creating a good picture of the "standard" immersion). Which is why I was hoping for more natural coefficients  But the answer, which I've accepted, is an excellent start. See also my comment about Stricland's edits.